# Why is my Stack Overflow chat profile linking to meta.stackoverflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Somebody noticed in chat that my profile no longer links to my Stack Overflow account, but to my meta SO account.

Why is it linking there when I'm on a Stack chat (JS)?

(I couldn't help but crop in the "danguhhhh zonneee", sorry)

Everybody else's link goes to Main, and mine used to as far as I can remember, but now it's not.

[image: clip from Pofile]

Comment: I'm wondering if the link goes to where your last action was.  My last action was posting this comment, let's see!  Edit: Nope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly? I have no idea how that happened. But I've switched it back to point to your Stack Overflow user.

Comment: Thank you. We were trying to figure out why as well. Nadda.

Comment: Mine is also linked to Meta. Conspiracy? Can this be fixed?

Comment: Same on my profile: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial Something funny is going on. :)

Comment: I've [noticed](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29690163#29690163) the same thing for [Jeffrey Bosboom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3614835/jeffrey-bosboom) too.